Experiencing a "File Not Found" error for the Node.js app deployed on Google Cloud Run
I'm encountering a "404 file not found" error when trying to deploy four web apps on a Node.js server using google cloud run. Everything works as expected in localhost.

Here are the scripts for my Node server:
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

// Middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(express.json());

const superadminBuildPath = path.join(__dirname, './superadmin/build');
const clubadminBuildPath = path.join(__dirname, './clubadmin/build');
const clubcastLPBuildPath = path.join(__dirname, './static-lp');
const clubsLPBuildPath = path.join(__dirname, './clubs-lp/dist');

// Serve static content of superadmin
app.use('/superadmin', express.static(superadminBuildPath));

// Serve static content of clubadmin
app.use('/clubadmin', express.static(clubadminBuildPath));

// Serve static content of static LP
app.use(express.static(clubcastLPBuildPath));

// Serve static content of clubs LP
app.use('/clubs', express.static(clubsLPBuildPath));


app.get('/clubadmin/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(clubadminBuildPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/superadmin/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(superadminBuildPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/clubs/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(clubsLPBuildPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(clubcastLPBuildPath, 'index.html'));
});


// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

Note: The clubadmin, supadmin, and clubs lp are React apps, while static lp is just a static site built using HTML, CSS, and JS.
Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Since you are asking for any assistance, see my following suggestions:

If you are using google cloud run deploy from source code check this.
If you are deploying with a Dockerfile, make sure to add a command to copy these folders in the build steps of the Dockerfile.

You can also use volumes with cloud run to serve static content. See this stackoverflow answer.
